# how to add an arrow image to my navigation bar in css3

Tags: html, css, html-lists

how to add an down arrow sign image in the navigation bar to indicate sub menu opening down`

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li> 
    <a href="#"> parent </a> 
            <ul>  
            <li> <a href="#"> child 1 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> chil2 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> child3 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> child4</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> child5</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> child6 </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> child7 </a></li>
            </ul>
     </li>`
```

my list is made like this and i want parent to show with an down arrow image indication it has child list below

Answer (score 2):

Give a class to the `li` which have a sub menu. Like this :

**HTML :**

```
   <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="sub-menu"> 
        <a href="#"> parent </a> 
                <ul>  
                <li> <a href="#"> child 1 </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> chil2 </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> child3 </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> child4</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> child5</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> child6 </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> child7 </a></li>
                </ul>
         </li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sub-menu
{
list-style-image:url('sqpurple.gif');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kuheb/1/)

Comment: can u help me with the url because whenever I specify url for my image browser never responds

Comment: Tell me your website folder structure, where is your page and image. Tell me  the path

Comment: the image n html page is in same one folder on my desktop below is the link of the image.C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\webpage\approved.jpg

Comment: the image n html page is in same one folder on my desktop below is the link of the image.C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\webpage\approved.jpg  but whenever i provide image's link it didn't work and nothing is displayed.           '.sub
{
    list-style-image:url('SpryMenuBarDown.png');
}
.sub:hover ul
{
    display:block;'

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave a comment on your question so I'm posting this as an answer.

There's many css menu codes online. A simple google search will give you many results. If you can't add an image using css and you haven't given any sample code to show what you want so I recommend you use something like http://cssmenumaker.com/

Answer (score 0):

When you want an arrow, imagine a `div` with some border width. Now if you reduce the height and width to 0, only the borders remain. If they are of different colors, think of the intersection of the borders, because there is no width or height, they will be reduced to triangles. So something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<style>
div { width: 0px; height: 0px; border-left: 5px solid black; border-top: 5px solid transparent; border-right: 5px solid transparent; border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```